# How to embedded Microsoft Bot Emulator on my website

Tags: botframework, emulation

I'm trying to have the bot emulator running on my website, so the user can add cards & contact and test it from the website.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [BotFramework-Webchat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)?

Comment: I did, however, I'm trying to run the **emulator** and **not an existing bot** that I deployed from Azure.

Comment: @Mick, it seems that I need to have an Azure account for that or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The Emulator is built on the WebChat application/source code. WebChat is a directline client for the directline channel. The emulator is used for development and testing. You can use webchat as a way to test, but you're not going to get some of the tools/benefits you get from Emulator. You *might* be able to take the [emulator source](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-emulator) code and build what you need, but that seems like a lot of work for so little benefit.

Your bot code does not have to be hosted in Azure, but for the simplest setup, you should create a bot channels registration in Azure and use that. Configure that to set your endpoint to wherever your bot code is running and then use the webchat channel and client.

Comment: Thank you @Dana-v ! I can't take the emulator source code since it's missing some files that fire the project (checked the gitignore).